# Изменить размер Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

```
       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/bacground_main">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:ignore="ScrollViewCount,UselessParent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:textAlignment="center">
                    <!-- Первая пара -->

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/buttonDateDialog"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                            android:onClick="OnClick"
                            android:text="@string/day" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewDay"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#fff"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            tools:ignore="UnknownId" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutOne"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_one"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_one"
                android:minHeight="100dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewOne"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="155dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_one_para"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_one_top"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_two" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_one_para"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/title_one_para"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_para" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

При нажатии на кнопку должен измениться размер layoutOne

```
 public void OnClick(View view) {
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutOne);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 300;
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Но вылетает ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.sfedu.schedule.sfedurasp, PID: 17448
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22462)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22462) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
                  at com.sfedu.schedule.sfedurasp.Main.OnClick(Main.java:19)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22462) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ошибке все написано:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

у вас RelativeLayout лежит в LinearLayout. Измените:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
```

На:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
```